# Find all maximal ideals of the ring $M=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \mid a \in \Bbb Z, b \in \Bbb R \right\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

My problem: 
$M=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}
\mid
a \in \Bbb Z, b \in \Bbb R
\right\}$.

I need to find all ideal I of M: M/I is a field.

We know that: An ideal I of a unitary commutative ring R is maximal iff R/I is a field.
But i don't know how to find all maximal ideal of M so i'm stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Prove that $M\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

The ring $M$ is isomorphic to the product ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$, so the problem is equivalent to finding the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$. Any ideal of $R \times S$ must be of the form $I \times J$ for some ideals $I$ of $R$ and $J$ of $S$, and $I \times J$ is maximal (or prime) iff either $I=R$ and $J$ is maximal (or prime), or $J=S$ and $I$ is maximal (or prime).

Hence, the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$ are $p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$ where $p$ is a prime number, and $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$.

Transporting to the ring $M$, we see that its maximal ideals are the following:

- The ideal of real diagonal $2 \times 2$ matrices where the top-left entry is an integer multiple of some fixed prime number $p$.
- The ideal of $2 \times 2$ matrices where the top-left entry is an integer and the other three entries are all zero.

Comment: I think The ideal of 2×2 matrices where the top-left entry is an integer and the bottom right entry is a real number. The other two entries are all zero.

Comment: @129492 A ring is not considered to be a maximal (or prime) ideal of itself.